# Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection Exception in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#

I am getting **Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.0.0** exception in .Net core 2.0. I tried installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.1.0 from Nuget but still the issue persists.
Any help is appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: If you're still using Net Core 2.0, maybe you need an older version? [2.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/2.2.0) seems to be the newest version that supports Net Core 2.0

Comment: I am getting the above issue with .Net Standard 2.0 as well

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection -Version 2.*"

It should be compatible with .Net core 2.0.

The one you are trying to install is 3.1 which has dependencies on .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Standard 2.0 When I Installed Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.1.0 from 3.1.3, the issue got resolved. I tried to adding binding in the app.config, but still it didn't work. Not sure why 3.1.0 version is required.